# Infinimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Given the following conditions:

$x \in \Bbb R$ and $y\in (0,1)$

I was asked to prove that

inf $ |x-y |=0 $

**My Attempt:**

By the elementary properties  of the modulus  function , we know that $ 0 \leq |x-y|$ $\forall x \in X  , y \in (0, 1)$. So clearly it bounded below by $0$.

Suppose there exist a $\epsilon > 0$ such that $ \epsilon \leq |x-y|$ $\forall x \in X  , y \in (0, 1)$. However letting $x= \epsilon$  and $y= \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon +1 } $ then $|x-y|< \epsilon $ So the exist no such $\epsilon>0$

Is this  correct and  sufficient enough?

Edit:
Well the proof suggest is a lot simpler and easier. I still would like to know whether what I provide constituents a proof.

Comment: Well, you can say that clearly $\inf |x-y|\geq 0$, and since for example taking $x = y = \frac{1}{2}$, then $|x-y|=0$, so $\inf |x-y|=0$.

Comment: @ImanolPérezArribas Thanks for the alternative easier and more obvious idea! Does my attempt proof if?

Comment: Yes, your proof is valid. However, you would have to say why $|x-y|<\epsilon$. $|x-y|= |\epsilon - \dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + 1}| = | \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon + 1}| < \epsilon$, since $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @ImanolPérezArribas I think its '\frac'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is valid. However, you would have to say why $|x-y|<\epsilon$.

$$|x-y|= \left |\epsilon - \dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + 1}\right | = \left | \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon + 1}\right | < \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$.

However, you can proof it much easier:

You can say that clearly $\inf|x−y|\geq 0$, and taking for example $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$, then $|x−y|=0$, so $\inf|x−y|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine. In this case, it can be made a little simpler.

Since $|z| \ge 0$ for all $z$, we have a lower bound of $0$.

Now choose $x=y = {1 \over 2}$. Then $|x-y| = 0$, hence the infimum is attained.